# mail going in spam folder

Tags: php, email

this is the mail body header subject and message

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "From: domin name" . PHP_EOL;
    $subject = "1+1 Weekend Bonanza from Pizza Hut";
$message = "";
$message .= '<html>
    message body
</html>';
```

*this is the mail function which i'm using.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);*
```

My mail always go in the spam folder help me to send it in the inbox as it is very important to send them in the inbox pleae help me out.

Thanks for help in advance.

I'm unable to post the image as my reputation is low. in place of image i have written their is a image.

Comment: If that email was sent to me then I'd *want* it to go to the spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

Email usually arrives to `span` because of bad headers. Try looking [here](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/).

```
<?php
  $headers .= "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n"
?>
```

Comment: thanks but not working.

Comment: @pradeep maybe you email client already black listed email address that you use?

Comment: how can i fix it any idea. as I am new in php.

Comment: @pradeep if you mean by 'blacklisted by email client', than it's nothing to do with PHP, just go to email client and move email from span, "teach your email".

Answer (score 0):

This additional headers for ur emails might help you

```
$subject = "1+1 Weekend Bonanza from Pizza Hut";
$header = "from: domin name \r"."<br >";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \r"."<br >";
$header .= "Return-Path: <mail@domainname.com> \r"."<br >";
$header .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest) \r"."<br >";
$header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High \r"."<br >";
$header .= "Importance: High \r"."<br >"; 
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r"."<br >";

$message = "<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />
//Add more here
```

Comment: thanks for help but not working.

Comment: I figured it out To send your mail to inbox you need to add this point mail($to,$subject,$message,$header,"-f info@yourdomain.com ") thanks for the help all of you.